# Автоинкремент по соседниму полю

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Задача сделать автоинкремент для поля position,но увеличиваться должен вределах одного значения в поле room_id.
Решение нужно на postgres или typeorm

| id | room_id | position | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | ... |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | ... |

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#beforeinsert сделать запрос максимальной позиции в рамках комнаты и добавить 1

Comment: Я уже пытался пользоватся этим декоратором, но не учел то что использовал метод insert. Поменял на create и все заработало.Спасибо

Comment: пожалуйста, напишите хороший ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: btw, при такой структуре данных position не нужен, можно использовать вместо него id

Comment: Модель сильно упрощена для примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {BeforeInsert} from 'typeorm';

class Code {
  @BeforeInsert()
  async incrementPosition() {
    const code = await Code.findOne({
      where: {
        room: this.room,
      },
      select: ['id', 'position'],
      order: {
        position: 'DESC',
      },
    })

    this.position = (code?.position ?? 0) + 1;
  }
}


Code.create({
  room: await Room.findOne(1),
}).save() // не используйте insert
```

Это мой вариант. Если кто то напишет свой вариант например на тригерах, буду признателен.